# Select images having a specific onmouseover call using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, mouseover

I have a php code that generates a piece of html code like this.

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" onmouseover="funct_update(1, 10, 21)" onclick="funct_click(...)" />
<img src="images/2.jpg" onmouseover="funct_update(5, 2, 9)" onclick="funct_click(...)" />
<img src="images/3.jpg" onmouseover="funct_update(8, 12, 100)" onclick="funct_click(...)" />
```

Now since I don't want to touch the PHP code, I wonder if it is possible to select, using jQuery, all images having as attribute `onmouseover="funct_update(.*)"` , and bind +1 function for onmouseover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a James Padolsey [regex filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) which can be used as follows:

```
$("img:regex(onmouseover, funct_update.*)").mouseover(function(){
    // Your New Function Here
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to intercept the onmouseover function you could take a look at this code from Ext JS: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.x/docs/source/Ext.html#method-Function-createInterceptor